# Resolving Images with div custom tags

Tags: 2013-sp1, image, link-resolver

We need to have background images in a div tag depending on the device, so it would be something like this :

```
<div data-bg-m="@@background-mobile@@" data-bg-d="@@background-desktop@@" style="background: url('@@background-desktop@@') no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
```

I have gone through the forums and understand that below [link](http://tridionbasicscity.com/2015/04/16/css-background-images-issue-in-tridion-with-inline-style/) will provide me with a solution for the inline styling or the tag for "style":

I have also gone through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514639/resolving-images-for-input-buttons-with-sdl-tridion-compound-templates) :  but couldnt make this to work for multiple images in the same div tag.

For now, we have images for desktop and mobile but it is possible to add another image in future for tablet or someother breakpoint? 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I was too fast in posting the question but I was able to answer my own question. For those, who find them in the same situation, just read through this [post](http://tridionbasicscity.com/2015/04/16/css-background-images-issue-in-tridion-with-inline-style/) carefully and implement a .net assembly. That will fix work for custom html tags as well.

The solution is to create a .Net Assembly Which searches for such CSS background image patterns and replaces them with appropriate URLs. or create a C# TBB which does the same thing.

The post above has the code snippet which can help

Comment: Could you please summarize the post here in this answer rather than just supplying a link? The link is fine, but a summary will give people a quick insight on this site already.

Comment: above comment edited to explain the solution